# npm build crashed on ssr

Tags: angular, npm, server-side-rendering

I want to implement SSR in my Angular app to improve Google crawling.
So I added the missing packages with the following command:
`npm install --save @angular/platform-server @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader ts-loader @nguniversal/express-engine`

If I execute the build command `npm run build:ssr` the following error occurs:

```
ERROR in D:\Documents\webapp\server.ts
./server.ts
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Documents\webapp\server.ts(24,20)
      TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof e' has no call signatures.
```

This is the server.ts:

```
/**
 * *** NOTE ON IMPORTING FROM ANGULAR AND NGUNIVERSAL IN THIS FILE ***
 *
 * If your application uses third-party dependencies, you'll need to
 * either use Webpack or the Angular CLI's `bundleDependencies` feature
 * in order to adequately package them for use on the server without a
 * node_modules directory.
 *
 * However, due to the nature of the CLI's `bundleDependencies`, importing
 * Angular in this file will create a different instance of Angular than
 * the version in the compiled application code. This leads to unavoidable
 * conflicts. Therefore, please do not explicitly import from @angular or
 * @nguniversal in this file. You can export any needed resources
 * from your application's main.server.ts file, as seen below with the
 * import for `ngExpressEngine`.
 */

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Express server
export const app = express();




const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});
```

If I use `npm run build` without ssr it works.

Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: Not enough information here. Suggestion: instead of using Universal, take a look at Scully.io - much easier.

Comment: @MikeOne Thanks for this hint. I want to remove all this stuff from angular/universal. So I uninstalled the packages and deleted the environment and the *.server files. But the building stops because of: `ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for D:/Documents/webapp/src/app/admin/pages/page-editor/page-editor.component.scss. Budget NaN undefined was not met by NaN undefined with a total of 90 bytes.`  This line occures for every component ... What is wrong?

Comment: You probably deleted a bit too much from angular.json..?